# Generic Pickle-Aware Super-Class for Mixing Classes with and without __slots__ in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, serialization

I want a generic super-class that I can easily subclass - and if desired add slots to my class - without having to worry about any pickle issues (with the lowest protocol). Is this in general a good idea? And if so, is this class a good implementation?

```
class HasSlots(object):
    """Top-class that allows mixing of classes with and without slots.

    Takes care that instances can still be pickled with the lowest
    protocol. Moreover, provides a generic `__dir__` method that
    lists all slots.

    """

    # We want to allow weak references to the objects
    __slots__ = ['__weakref__']  

    def _get_all_slots(self):
        """Returns all slots as set"""
        all_slots = (getattr(cls, '__slots__', []) 
                         for cls in self.__class__.__mro__)
        return set(slot for slots in all_slots for slot in slots)

    def __getstate__(self):
        if hasattr(self, '__dict__'):
            # We don't require that all sub-classes also define slots,
            # so they may provide a dictionary
            statedict = self.__dict__.copy()
        else:
            statedict = {}
        # Get all slots of potential parent classes
        for slot in self._get_all_slots():
            try:
                value = getattr(self, slot)
                statedict[slot] = value
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        # Pop slots that cannot or should not be pickled
        statedict.pop('__dict__', None)
        statedict.pop('__weakref__', None)
        return statedict

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        for key, value in state.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

    def __dir__(self):
        result = dir(self.__class__)
        result.extend(self._get_all_slots())
        if hasattr(self, '__dict__'):
            result.extend(self.__dict__.keys())
        return result
```

Thus, I can simply sub-class this without worrying about slots and pickle:

```
class MyClass(HasSlots):
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
```

but later maybe I want to optimize it and simply add some slots:

```
class MySlotClass(HasSlots):
    __slots__ = ['_x', '_y']
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
```

And I still want to guarantee that my new object can be pickled:

```
import pickle
pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(MyClass(1,2))
pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(MySlotClass(1,2))
```

Are there any serious issues with my idea and implementation? Is this: `all_slots = (getattr(cls, '__slots__', []) for cls in self.__class__.__mro__)` a good approach to take care that all slots are properly pickled?

Is the approach safe for sub-classes that reference each other in a circular fashion?

Comment: Can you specify Python 2 vs Python 3 (or both)? Also, if you're on Python 2 have you considered using a higher `pickle` protocol version?

Comment: Basically I'm talking about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522765/python-pickling-slots-error. Is that the issue you're trying to get around?

Comment: The class should work with Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4. Moreover, I have to use the lowest Pickle Protocol because the instances will be used in a multiprocessing environment and `fork` is not always available.

Comment: Can you explain what the problem with higher pickle versions and `fork` is? It's not too clear to me. Are you talking about `multiprocessing`? It seems to use `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.6/Modules/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.c#L231.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I fell for this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920601/python-multiprocessing-pickle-protocol. Anyhow, this is still useful if I don't want to write __getstate__ and __setstate__ in every subclass, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few of trivial points:

- `getattr(cls, '__slots__', [])` would be better as `getattr(..., ())` - tuples are immutable so are normally cached by the implementation.
- `set(slot for slots in all_slots for slot in slots)` would be better as `{slot for slots in all_slots for slot in slots}`
- It might be better to do

  ```
  try:
      statedict = vars(self).copy()
  except TypeError:
      statedict = {}
  ```